# Is the semicubical parabola differentiable?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
The image of the curve looks like the semicubical parabola.

I wanted to know if $\alpha$ is differentiable.
The component functions are both differentiable, with
$\alpha'(t)=(2t,3t^2)$
But looking at its image, it should not be differentiable in $t=0$.

I am a little bit confused, because as far as I know,
if $f :[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Then f is differentiable in $x_0$ if every component function $f_1,...,f_n$ is differentiable in $x_0$.

I did some thinking/calculating and on one hand $\alpha$ should be differnetiable, but on the other hand the curve $\beta(t)=(x,x^{2/3})$ has the same image whilst not being differentiable in $0$.

Is $\alpha$ differentiable in $0$ (and why/why not)?
Are there "representation functions" of a image that are not differentiable and other representations that are?

**Edit:**
I meant, the graph of the function $\beta(t)=x^{2/3}$ is the same as the image of $\alpha$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a map to $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\beta$ is a map to $\Bbb{R}$.  Why should the differentiability of one be tied to the differentiability of the other?

Comment: @EricTowers They have the same image and differentiability ensures some kind of "smoothness". So I thought why should the same "image" habe a differentiable and a not differentiable "representation".

Comment: Looking at a function and looking at its image are two different questions. Are you asking if the image is a differentiable submanifold of the plane?

Comment: They do *NOT* have the same image -- one image is a set of real numbers and one image is a set of points in the plane.  They don't even have the same graph -- one graph lives in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and one graph lives in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiability is a property of a function, not a property of a curve. The example you found
$$\alpha(t)=(t^2,t^3),$$
$$\beta(t)=(t,t^{3/2})$$
shows that it is possible for a differentiable function and a non-differentiable  function to trace the same curve (for $t\geq 0$ in this example).

In the comments, you mention that differentiablility ensures some kind of smoothness. This is true, but the object that is smooth is the *graph* of the function. The non-smooth parametric curve traced by $\alpha(t)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is not the graph of $\alpha$. The graph of $\alpha$ includes a coordinate for the input $t$ as well. In other words, the graph of $\alpha$ is the curve traced by $(t,t^2,t^3)$ in $\mathbb R^3$, and it is smooth (the cusp at $t=0$ disappears). Furthermore, the graph of $\beta$ is different from the graph of $\alpha$, and it is not smooth.